# Artifactory as Docker Registry through Nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, artifactory

I"m having issues with Artifactory as a docker registry.

Artifactory and Nginix are on one machine both running inside their own docker containers. Artifactory is setup to use a revers proxy using sub domains. The DNS server has been updated with the sub domains and Nginx has been loaded with a Wildcard SSL Certificate. The client machines have been loaded with Cert files so they accept the self signed certificate.

I have no problem accessing Artifactory on an http or https port. Jenkins pushes and pulls fine.

Docker on the other hand doesn't want to work properly. A couple of strange things are happening.

1) the docker login command works and shows login successful. However in the Artifactory

```
2018-03-20 21:40:03,602 [DENIED LOGIN]  for NA/172.17.0.3.
2018-03-20 21:40:14,358 [DENIED LOGIN]  for NA/172.17.0.3.
2018-03-20 21:40:47,716 [DENIED LOGIN]  for NA/172.17.0.3.
2018-03-20 21:40:57,874 [DENIED LOGIN]  for NA/172.17.0.3.
```

172.17.0.3 is Artifactory's internal IP inside the Docker container. I'm guessing something is happening to the login between the client and Artifactory when the data goes through Nginx

2) docker push starts pushing. But when the layer reaches 100% it retries over and over until it times out. But this causes incomplete files showing up in Artifactory. If I try and delete one through curl or in the browser I get an error

```
Failed to delete item with id '14052': ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

But the corresponding item with these ids are still in the Oracle DB and have to be manual deleted to remove them from Artifactory.

3) When the push happens it causing some strange messages in the log file.

```
2018-03-20 21:10:04,242 [DENIED LOGIN]  for NA/172.17.0.1.
2018-03-20 21:10:04,873 [ACCEPTED DEPLOY] docker-local:dpa-base/_uploads/415150da-c6ce-458c-87c4-765838e7c38e for ppapp/172.17.0.1.
2018-03-20 21:10:05,441 [ACCEPTED DELETE] docker-local:dpa-base/_uploads/415150da-c6ce-458c-87c4-765838e7c38e for _system_.
2018-03-20 21:10:07,339 [ACCEPTED DEPLOY] docker-local:dpa-base/_uploads/6ccd5e57-b237-451e-b547-581618b5227a for ppapp/172.17.0.1.
2018-03-20 21:10:07,468 [ACCEPTED DEPLOY] docker-local:dpa-base/_uploads/03bb5d96-7ce0-468b-ab0f-d3a08efcdccb for ppapp/172.17.0.1.
2018-03-20 21:10:07,501 [ACCEPTED DELETE] docker-local:dpa-base/_uploads/6ccd5e57-b237-451e-b547-581618b5227a for _system_.
2018-03-20 21:10:07,568 [ACCEPTED DELETE] docker-local:dpa-base/_uploads/03bb5d96-7ce0-468b-ab0f-d3a08efcdccb for _system_.
2018-03-20 21:10:07,728 [ACCEPTED DEPLOY] docker-local:dpa-base/_uploads/3c445392-7ff2-4375-b55a-f041edda1160 for ppapp/172.17.0.1.
2018-03-20 21:10:07,938 [ACCEPTED DELETE] docker-local:dpa-base/_uploads/3c445392-7ff2-4375-b55a-f041edda1160 for _system_.
2018-03-20 21:10:45,796 [DENIED LOGIN]  for NA/172.17.0.1.
2018-03-20 21:10:46,551 [ACCEPTED DEPLOY] docker-local:docker/dpa-base/_uploads/716bc4bf-dea7-4da8-a31d-8c4e7ea54fdc for ppapp/172.17.0.1.
2018-03-20 21:10:46,698 [ACCEPTED DELETE] docker-local:docker/dpa-base/_uploads/716bc4bf-dea7-4da8-a31d-8c4e7ea54fdc for _system_.
2018-03-20 21:10:48,632 [ACCEPTED DEPLOY] docker-local:docker/dpa-base/_uploads/51df5746-e96e-43c5-8473-20083690a5bf for ppapp/172.17.0.1.
2018-03-20 21:10:48,774 [ACCEPTED DELETE] docker-local:docker/dpa-base/_uploads/51df5746-e96e-43c5-8473-20083690a5bf for _system_.
2018-03-20 21:10:48,866 [ACCEPTED DEPLOY] docker-local:docker/dpa-base/_uploads/1f76e046-a574-407a-86b1-619e0b777ed7 for ppapp/172.17.0.1.
2018-03-20 21:10:48,995 [ACCEPTED DEPLOY] docker-local:docker/dpa-base/_uploads/6b517a6c-94c9-4ca4-8a35-30d327022a05 for ppapp/172.17.0.1.
2018-03-20 21:10:49,041 [ACCEPTED DELETE] docker-local:docker/dpa-base/_uploads/1f76e046-a574-407a-86b1-619e0b777ed7 for _system_.
2018-03-20 21:10:49,203 [ACCEPTED DELETE] docker-local:docker/dpa-base/_uploads/6b517a6c-94c9-4ca4-8a35-30d327022a05 for _system_.
```

I'm not too sure what's going on here. Any help would be great.